# Corona sdk : stop audio when another starts / launch audio just once

Tags: audio, coronasdk

I want to stop a sound when another starts playing .

```
if (event.object1.myName == "obst3") then 
audio.play(colsound)
```

I want this one to stop if  the following one starts .

```
if (event.object1.myName == "t") then
    audio.play(explosion)
```

Also, I need to know how to launch the sound just once ( when my objects collide with a wall, a sound pop out I need this one to be heard just once even if the player touches again the wall.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play every audio with reference id value :

```
    if (event.object1.myName == "obst3") then 
       local isChannel1Playing = audio.isChannelPlaying( 2 )
       if isChannel1Playing then
         audio.stop( playLaserSound2 )
         playLaserSound2 = nil
       end
       playLaserSound1  = audio.play(colsound, { channel=1 })
    end
   if (event.object1.myName == "t") then
      local isChannel1Playing = audio.isChannelPlaying( 1 )
       if isChannel1Playing then
         audio.stop( playLaserSound1 )
         playLaserSound1 = nil
       end
      playLaserSound2 = audio.play(explosion, { channel=2 })
   end
```

Comment: thank you @AndroidUser it works, can you explain the playerLaserSound1 = nil utility  ?

Comment: Clearing the reference playerLaserSound1.bcs again you are going to use that variable.